# How to change color of options in list onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My HTML code:

```
<li onclick="switchColors()">
    <a class="x" href="Faculty.php">Faculty</a>
 </li>
<li onclick="switchColors()">
   <a class="x" href="Contact.php">Contact</a>
</li>
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
<script>
  function switchColors(element)  
  {  
    links=document.getElementsByTagName("li") ;  
    for (var i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i ++)  
    links.item(i).style.color = 'orange' ;  
     element.style.color='purple' ;  
   } 
</script>
```

What i want to do is that when i click on "Faculty" it loads Faculty.php page and change "Faculty" color into purple and "Faculty" remains in purple untill i click on "Contact". And when i click on "Contact" it load Contact.php page and change "Contact" color into purple, and also set "Faculty" to orange color.

I tried the above JS code but it don't work, when i click on "Faculty" it load Facult.php page but don't change "Faculty" into purple color.

How should i do that?

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too broad.

Comment: Also, the title of the question should be a short, on-the-point and properly written.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Title should not be more than 150 characters, but i could't summarize my title in 150 characters.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried a lot bro!

Comment: The title should be something like "Toggle options on click" and not the complete question crammed in.

Comment: _"I tried a lot"_ - Then you need to show us your attempts, explain what happen when you execute it and what suppose to happen. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Now question is understandable?

Answer (score -1):

this doesn't work with javascript "onClick" event. because your page refreshes.

you need to set a variable in your PHP and set the page name to that. and then have an "if" in PHP to declare which page you are then set class for your "li" element to change its color.

A guide is in link below:

https://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent/

Comment: This is not helpful!